# What to do when you don't want to award your bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I started a bounty on [Infinite Scroll not working in own theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83328/infinite-scroll-not-working-in-own-theme) and found out the answer myself. I do not consider the answer of Otto worth the bounty. What should I do? What happens when I do not select one for the bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.
>
> [privileges > set bounties](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties)

Answer (score 1):

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> If after the end of the bounty period a question has no answers, no bounty will be awarded and the question will no longer be featured.
>
> Bounties are best understood as exchanging reputation for higher question visibility and increased answerer motivation. A bounty does not guarantee a response and is not refunded if none are received.

You cannot award the bounty to your own answer, so the bounty is lost.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not consider the answer of Otto worth the bounty. What should I do?

Nothing. If you don't want to award a bounty, let it disappear.